# Create simple bar chart from data frame with many columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to create a simple bar chart from a pandas data frame that looks like this:

A  a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6...

B  b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6...

C  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6...

The values are float numbers and there are over 2000 columns
The chart should have 3 bars in total with A,B,C on the x axis.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) first and then plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df.sum(axis=1).plot.bar()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3],
                   2:[4,5,6],
                   3:[7,8,9]}, index=list('ABC')) * 0.8

print (df)
     1    2    3
A  0.8  3.2  5.6
B  1.6  4.0  6.4
C  2.4  4.8  7.2

print (df.sum(axis=1))
A     9.6
B    12.0
C    14.4
dtype: float64

df.sum(axis=1).plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Actually in my case the mean value is needed not the sum, but still exactly the info I missed to continue, thanks again!